# Date changes when setValues() is called

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written a script for a client in a Spreadsheet whose time is GMT-5 while my TimeZone is GMT+5. The column H on the spreadsheet's tab has a value as date without any time factor e.g. 01/25/2019.

On the start of script function I am setting the format of column like under the following `.setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")`. Also note that I am working with `.getDisplayValues()` which returns me test for the Date column.

There is nowhere in the script I am explicitly updating `DateValue` its value. After manipulating some other values on the other column I happen to update the row by calling the `.setValues([row])`.

Then the date changes to 01/24/2019 and when I change the format to include time factor then it is like 01/24/2020 19:00:00.

Interesting point is it does not occur on my end where my timeZone is GMT+5. Even though I changed the Spreadsheet's Timezone to GMT-5 and on my system as well but still it doesn't occur on my end but on the client machine.

The runtime version of the script is:

> "runtimeVersion": "V8"

Comment: Your time zones are 10 hours apart. What do you want to happen? If you did a setValues() that included column H then you updated the date.

Comment: I m curious over that if read value is 01/25/2019 and explicitly the script didnot change value in the column then why .setValue([row]) is changing the date 01/24/2019 19:00:00. It should have remain what was read in the start i.e. 01/25/2019

Comment: You said that you were user `setValues([row]).` and that's a 2 dimensional array write [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))

Comment: Cooper ofcourse its a 2 dimensional array.

Comment: Well I don't know why don't post your code but I assume if your wrote to a row that you also wrote into column H.  But maybe I'm and that's easy to determine by you providing a [mcve]

Comment: Fairly certain that the reason is in the `getDisplayValues()` - if you would have used the `getValues()` to get the actual value, then the issue shouldn't have happened. Agreed with Cooper - you should post either an MRE or parts of the code. Better, an MRE, as you are likely to catch the issue while trying to reproduce

Comment: `function updatePatientTransactions(transactionSheetValues, patientNam, insuranceName)
{
    var tempRow                = [];
    
    for(var i= start; i<= end-2; i++)
    {
      tempRow                 = transactionSheetValues[i];     
      tempRow[0]                = patientName;
      tempRow[3]                = insuranceName;
      transactionSheet.getRange(i+2,1,1,transactionSheet.getLastColumn()).setValues([tempRow]);
    } 
  } 
}`

Comment: Post it into the question  please.

Answer (score 1):

### This can happen when the script time zone and spreadsheet time zone are different and you format the date object

I cannot reproduce your exact situation from the information you provided, but I invite you to do the following test:

1. Set your spreadsheet timezone to any timezone that is ahead of your script time zone
2. Set cell `A1` of your active sheet to `=today()`
3. Run the following code:

```
function myFunction(){
  var displayDate = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").getDisplayValue();
  Logger.log("displayDate: " + displayDate);
  var date = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").getValue();
  Logger.log("actual date retrieved by Apps Script: " + date);
  var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  Logger.log("ScriptTimeZone: " + timeZone);
  var timezone2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  Logger.log("SpreadsheetTimeZone: " + timezone2);
  var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, "MM/dd/yyyy");
  Logger.log("formatted date that will be set back to the spreadsheet: " + newDate);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").setValue(newDate);
}



function updatePatientTransactions(transactionSheetValues, patientNam, insuranceName) { 
  var tempRow                = [];   
  for(var i= start; i<= end-2; i++)     {   
    tempRow                 = transactionSheetValues[i];     
    tempRow[0]                = patientName;  
    tempRow[3]                = insuranceName;  
    transactionSheet.getRange(i+2,1,1,transactionSheet.getLastColumn()).setValues([tempRow]);  

  }
}
```

4. Observe the logs and the output

Sample logs:

```
Stackdriver logs
Jun 8, 2020, 1:03:00 PM Info    displayDate: 6/8/2020
Jun 8, 2020, 1:03:01 PM Info    actual date retrieved by Apps Script: Sun Jun 07 2020 23:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
Jun 8, 2020, 1:03:01 PM Info    ScriptTimeZone: Europe/Paris
Jun 8, 2020, 1:03:01 PM Info    SpreadsheetTimeZone: Europe/Athens
Jun 8, 2020, 1:03:01 PM Info    formatted date that will be set back to the spreadsheet: 06/07/2020
```

so the date will be set back to yesterday.

### Why?

- When you retrieve a value that is formatted as `Date` and not `Date Time`, that is if the time is not set - Apps Script automatically sets it to midnight.
- When it is the 8th of June midnight in Athens, it is the 7th of June 23:00 o'clock in Paris
- This is why the conversion from a spreadsheet timezone to a script timezone lying behind will lead to a date change
- Now, if you format the date value as a date string or process it otherwise, the informaiton about the original timezone might get lost and when you set the datestring back to the spreadsheet, you will set back the Apps Script date - different from the spreadsheet date - so be careful!